# Docker image builds a different version of app

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use a docker image and it's showing a different behavior depending on how I use it.

The image is https://hub.docker.com/r/chriszarate/wordpress-phpunit/

Github is https://github.com/chriszarate/wordpress-phpunit

**Usage 1 - Building it locally**

1. Clone the repository
2. Run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm wordpress_phpunit php -v`

Output:

```
PHP 7.2.10 (cli) (built: Sep 17 2018 09:23:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans
```

**Usage 2 - Using it in my docker-compose.yml**

1. My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  wordpress_phpunit:
    image: "chriszarate/wordpress-phpunit"
```

2. Run `Run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm wordpress_phpunit php -v`

Output:

```
PHP 7.1.5 (cli) (built: May 13 2017 10:49:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.5, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Notice that the **Usage 1** installs **PHP 7.2.10** whereas **Usage 2** installs **PHP 7.1.5**

I've looked at the Docker hub and it has the latest changes from the git repository.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So, I'm very new to Docker, but here's a guess: when you `docker pull` the image from the docker repository (what it does in your second example), I believe it just fetches the image that was stored there to begin with (it doesn't rebuild it). Whereas when you `git pull` the actual Dockerfile / docker-compose.yml, it rebuilds the image locally. Since that Dockerfile has `RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-client php7-mysqli subversion wget`, I'm guessing that apk command retrieves a more recent version of PHP.

Comment: @Jeto That's what I looked into at first, `php7-mysqli` does not pull PHP itself.

Comment: Right. [phpunit does](https://github.com/JulienBreux/phpunit-docker/blob/master/6.0.6/Dockerfile). So I'm guessing that version of the phpunit docker image was built/pushed twice to the docker repository (PHP 7 had been updated before the second time), and the wordpress-phpunit image was built/pushed in between. Or something like this.

Comment: @Jeto Aha!! That makes sense. That must be the reason. Could you please post it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's what *might* have happened:

1. The `phpunit-docker/6.0.6` docker image was initially built and pushed to the docker repository. At that point, PHP 7 was in version 7.1.5, so the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/JulienBreux/phpunit-docker/blob/master/6.0.6/Dockerfile) built that version into the image.
2. The `chriszarate/wordpress-phpunit` docker image was then built. Since it's based on `phpunit-docker/6.0.6`, the generated image had PHP 7.1.5 built into it.
3. Then sometime later, the `phpunit-docker/6.0.6` was built and pushed again to the docker repository. Except this time, PHP 7 was in version 7.2.10. That's definitely odd, and should probably have not happened, though.

So, in this scenario:

- if you `docker pull chriszarate/wordpress-phpunit`, you'll get PHP 7.1.5 as it's built into its stored image on the docker repository,
- if you `git pull` its corresponding project instead, and *then* build it locally, it'll be based on the up-to-date `phpunit-docker/6.0.6` image, therefore running PHP 7.2.10.

Note that there might be other explanations. This one seems reasonable enough though.